# howto get task result with withDiscardingTaskGroup in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

In Swift, `withTaskGroup` is used to get task completed data as:

```swift
let test1 = await withTaskGroup { grp in
    grp.addTask { "Task 1 data" }
    grp.addTask { "Task 2 data" }
}
         
for await result in grp {
    print(result) // got task completed data
}
```

How we can get data from task completed by`withDiscardingTaskGroup`?

```swift
let test1 = await withDiscardingTaskGroup {grp in
    grp.addTask { "Task 1 data" }
    grp.addTask { "Task 2 data" }
}
```

Comment: You cannot, and that's the whole point of `withDiscardingTaskGroup`.

Comment: what about withDiscardingTaskGroup(returning: [String].self), how it return data

Comment: I had suspected that you are asking about that, and I addressed that at the end of my answer. I recommend editing the question to make it clear that you are asking about that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of [`DiscardingTaskGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/discardingtaskgroup) is to *discard* the results of child tasks. If you want results from child tasks, use a regular task group.

This is useful if the child tasks produce side effects, instead of returning values. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withdiscardingtaskgroup(returning:body:)) says:

> This [...] is best applied in situations where the result of a child task is some form of side-effect.

A discarding task group is kind of similar to a bunch of `async let`s of type `Void`:

```
async let sideEffect1: Void = doSomethingAsync1()
async let sideEffect2: Void = doSomethingAsync2()
async let sideEffect3: Void = doSomethingAsync3()
await [sideEffect1, sideEffect2, sideEffect3]
```

Of course, the main difference is that a task group can have a dynamic number of child tasks.

---

Side note: although the child tasks' results are discarded, the task group can still produce its own result, e.g.

```
let result = await withDiscardingTaskGroup(returning: Int.self) { group in
    // side effects...
    group.addTask { ... }
    group.addTask { ... }
    group.addTask { ... }

    // the group's own result
    return await getSomeIntegerAsynchronously()
}
```

`getSomeIntegerAsynchronously` will not wait for the child tasks to complete, and will run in parallel with the child tasks. `withDiscardingTaskGroup` however, *will* wait for all the child tasks, and also `getSomeIntegerAsynchronously`, to complete, before returning.